# Presenting a view controller with dim background

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, opacity, presentviewcontroller

I have a view controller which view's background I need to be translucent and keep showing the view below. I've adjusted the opacity in the `nib` file and tried both pushing the view controller into a navigation stack and presenting it modally, but when loaded, the previous view is unloaded. How could I solve this?

Comment: You need make a screenshot previous view controller and set it to your modally presented view controller as a background image

Comment: View Controllers within a `UINavigationController` are not unloaded until they are popped off by navigating "back". Can you be clearer about your issue by adding an image of the issue and an image of what you expect to happen?

Comment: @RoboticCat I see that the former view is shown below the one I'm presenting on top while the animation of the navigation, both if I push it onto a navigation stack or present it modally, but when this animation ends and the view fully occupies the screen, the former view "disappears" and then I see a black background

Answer (score 23):

Is this what you're looking for?

View Controller A -> View Controller B (nib)

**Swift < 3:**

In View Controller A, add the following line of code:

```
let viewControllerB = ViewControllerB(nibName: "ViewControllerB", bundle: nil)
viewControllerB.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen

presentViewController(viewControllerB, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And in View Controller B, set the background color of `view` with `colorWithAlphaComponent` method:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.7)
```

**Swift ≥ 3:**

View Controller A:

```
let viewControllerB = ViewControllerB(nibName: "ViewControllerB", bundle: nil)
viewControllerB.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen

present(viewControllerB, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

View Controller B:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
```

Comment: Awesome.. Worked for me. .Thanks @Anh Pham

Answer (score 3):

You can use `UIView` instead of a view controller.
Then adjust the alpha of view's background color.

Comment: This is the proper answer. When I try to pop over a new VC, the original one disappears as soon as the animation finishes. So I rather use a view only for that.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3.0 Code**

```
let addIncidentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addIncidentViewController") as! AddIncidentViewController
addIncidentViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.present(addIncidentViewController, animated: true) {

    }
```

And set background color with some alpha.

Answer (score 2):

AppsDev,

Is this what you are looking for buddy ??? Here *Testing1234* is a label added to parentViewController *Me here* is a label added to childViewController which is presented modally :)

[image]

If your answer is yes, Here is how you can do it :) Assuming you are uisng storyboard I'll write the answer :) If you are using Xib dont worry all these properties can be set programmatically as well :)

The main point here is to do the `modal presentation` `overfull screen` :)

Here is how you can do it :)

Drag a segue between your two ViewControllers :) Make the segue to present the viewController modally and select the following configurations :)
[image]

Now select your parent ViewController which will present the secondViewController and change its background color to white (or whatever color you want)

[image]

Now select your secondViewController which needs to be presented :) Select its View and set its alpha to 0.5 and color to clear color as shown below

[image]

Now add anotherView to the viewController set its color to black and alpha to 0.5 or 0.6 depending on your need for shade :)

[image]

Now add whatever the view components you want to add on top of it run and you will se the out put as shown above :)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes, I want something like that, but I'm managing separated `nib` files

Comment: @appsdev : Should not be an issue isnt it buddy :) Simply set its backlground colors the way mentioned and finally when you load it programmatically make sure you present it nodally and over full screen :)

Comment: I've set `UIModalPresentationStyle.OverFullScreen` but it doesn't work for me :S

Comment: hmmm :) Whats the issue ???? Have you set the background color of your xib to clear color and added a new view on top of it with black color and alpha as 0.5 ???? The output Ive attached is a executing code's output should work fine :)

Comment: This is the best answer on stack over flow for this problem... I have tried many many solutions and finally came to this.. Thank u boss!!

Comment: How to change the opacity?

Answer (score 2):

**Swift3**

Under `viewWillAppear` you can use:

```
self.view.alpha = 0.8
```

And under `viewWillDisappear` you can use:

```
self.view.alpha = 1.0
```

Comment: Is it possible that this answer just makes the background turn black?. OP mentioned the view should still be seen, but when I change the `alpha` of the view, it is just black.

Comment: The background should turn black only if the alpha value was 0. In this case it's set at 0.8 so the background would be lightly dimmed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to present ViewController with opacity view.

Over  current viewcontroller

```
// presenting view controller
definesPresentationContext = true

// presented view controller
modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

If view controller has navigation or tabbar over fullscreen.

```
// presented view controller
modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
```

Comment: How can I change the opacity?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine situation, that you want to use your view controller in multiple places (let's say you're creating framework). You need to set `modalPresentationStyle` to `.overCurrentContext`, but you don't want to set it every time you create new instance of view controller.

You want to set it inside overridden `init` of view controller which will be presented

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

then in `viewDidLoad()` of this controller just background color to lighter shade of black:

```
override public func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
}
```

Finally, when you need to present your view controller, just initialize it and present it

```
let viewController = SecondViewController(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)
present(viewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

(Swift 3) Better solution is to load the view from xib and then add it to the controller like so :

```
   let supportView =  Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("YourXIB", owner: nil, options: nil)?[0] as! YourView

    let viewController = UIViewController()
    viewController.view = supportView
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

    present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)e
```

And then add some transparency :

```
    viewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.7)
```